# Power BI to PolyBase to Cloudera Data Platform?

Tags: powerbi, cloudera, power-bi-report-server, polybase

Does anyone know if it's possible to connect a Power BI report to data in Cloudera Data Platform via PolyBase? I know you can get PolyBase to work with CDH, but I've not seen anything about CDP.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect to CDP via Impala:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-impala

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you may not find much yet on connecting to the Cloudera Data Platform, CDP is that it is the newest generation of the Big Data Platform.

Another thing to note, is that CDP is an entire platform, so there are many things you may want to connect with. The most likely tools being Hive and Impala and the most likely forms being the Data Hub and the Data Platform.

The good news:

Though it will take some time for the blogosphere to catch up, and articles to be written or re-written, CDP pretty much encompasses the capabilities of its predecessors CDH and HDP. As such, if you have something that works with either CDH or HDP in the field of connecting to data, it is almost certain to be possible with CDP as well.

To answer concretely: It is definitely possible to leverage any BI tool, including Power BI on top of the data in CDP.

Full Disclosure: I am an Employee of Cloudera.